# Old version of checkstyle detected. Consider updating to >= v8.30

Tags: maven, sonarqube, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

Small question regarding a SonarQube + Checkstyle warning please.

Currently, in my app, in my pom, I use the following Checkstyle plugin:

```
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputFile>.out/reports/checkstyle/checkstyle-result.xml</outputFile>
                    <outputDirectory>target/reports/checkstyle</outputDirectory>
                    <outputFileFormat>xml</outputFileFormat>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

This plugin is doing its job, no worries there.

When I run SonarQube though, I get this warning

```
Old version of checkstyle detected. Consider updating to >= v8.30
For more information see: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/upgrading-checkstyle.html
```

I obviously went to read the website, but I am still having hard time understanding.

The Checkstyle plugin I have is the latest known, version 3.1.2, checked on Maven central etc.

In SonarQube, I am running on the latest version, 8.9 LTS, with the latest version of Checkstyle plugin as well.

What am I missing please? Am I using some kind of wrong plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a **SonarQube** plugin named `sonar-checkstyle` which needs to be installed or upgraded at the **SonarQube** server instance. The current version is `8.40`.

Note: Refer to

- https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/install-plugin/
- https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/plugin-version-matrix/
- https://github.com/checkstyle/sonar-checkstyle
- https://github.com/checkstyle/sonar-checkstyle/releases

### Edit 1

#### Step 1

Firstly, there is a `cache` directory at `<user_home>/.sonar/cache` (for me on the Windows 10 is `C:\Users\<myuser>\.sonar\cache`), please delete all `sub directories` under this `cache` directory with purpose to let the `org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin` *latest version* download it from our **SonarQube** server instance and ensure that all related plugins are new and fresh after upgrading/installing at the **SonarQube** server instance. (Do not forget to restart it after finishing upgrading/installing to ensure all new are re-loaded)

#### Step 2

Secondly, make sure that we do not specify the `org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin` in our project `pom.xml` neither at the parent nor anywhere else with purpose to ensure that during executing, it will be a *latest version* which matches to our **SonarQube** server instance `version`.

Anyhow the formal document (https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/) also mentions about *How to Fix Version of Maven Plugin* as the following: -

> How to Fix Version of Maven Plugin
>
> It is recommended to lock down versions of Maven plugins:

```xml
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>
        <!--Version that matched with our Sonar server instance version --> 
        </version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

The latest version is able to be browsed at https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/sonar-maven-plugin or https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.sonarsource.scanner.maven/sonar-maven-plugin The latest is version `3.9.0.2155` (*Note: the version `?.y.z` is matched with our Sonar server instance version*)

#### Step 3

Last but not least, if our project is a `multi-module projects` there is a mentioned at the formal document (https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-maven/) as the following: -

> In some situations you may want to run the sonar:sonar goal as a
> dedicated step. Be sure to use install as first step for multi-module
> projects
>
> mvn clean install
>
> mvn sonar:sonar ...

Then there will be 2 steps here, `mvn clean install` first so that it is completed and then `mvn sonar:sonar ...` later on.

### Edit 2

The `maven-checkstyle-plugin` is also able to specify the `checkstyle version` as mentioned at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/upgrading-checkstyle.html with the significant sentence as

> Maven Checkstyle plugin comes with a default Checkstyle version: for
> maven-checkstyle-plugin 3.1.2, ***Checkstyle 8.29*** is used by default.

Then the configuration for the `maven-checkstyle-plugin` will be like the following: -

```xml
    <project>
      ...
      <build>
        <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>3.1.2</version>
              <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                  <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                  <version>...choose your version...</version>
                </dependency>
              </dependencies>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
      <build>
      ...
    </project>
```

The latest version is able to be browsed at https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.puppycrawl.tools/checkstyle The latest is version `8.42`.

Comment: Learned something new, I was looking at the wrong place (my java project) all that time. Thanks a lot

Comment: I just checked, and unfortunately, even after upgrading SonarQube to the latest LTS 8.9, which has the Checkstyle 8.40, the message still appears 